# jquery function doesn't return values correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function

```
$.fn.validate.checkValidationName = function(id) {
 $.post("PHP/submitButtonName.php", {checkValidation: id},
     function(data) {
  if(data.returnValue === true) {
         name = true;
  } else {
      name = false;
  } 
  **console.log("name = "+name); **//this prints out "true"****  
 }, "json");
};
```

and this .click function that calls it. All the variables are declared outside this function so that they should be accessible by other functions

```
$('.submitBtn').click(function() {
 //clears the array before re-submitting the click function
 nameValues = [];
 usernameValues = [];
 emailValues = [];
 name = false;
 username = false;
 email = false;

 //for each of the input tags
 $("input").each(function() {

        //if the curent input tag has the class .name, .userpass, or .email
     if(($(this).hasClass("name"))) {
         nameValues.push($(this).val());
     } else if(($(this).hasClass("userpass"))) {
      usernameValues.push($(this).val());
     } else if(($(this).hasClass("email"))) {
      emailValues.push($(this).val());
     } 

 });
 //call the checkValidation function with the array "values"
 $.fn.validate.checkValidationName(nameValues);
 $.fn.validate.checkValidationUsername(usernameValues);
 $.fn.validate.checkValidationEmail(emailValues);

 console.log("name = "+name); //but this prints out "false"
 console.log("username = "+username);
 console.log("email = "+email);

 if((name === "true") && (username === "true") && (email === "true")) {
     alert("Everything checks out great"); 
 } else {
     alert("You missed one!"); 
 }
});
```

When I click the link to trigger the first function, it returns the value as "true" inside the function, but when I `console.log("name"+name);` in the .click function after the function call, it prints out false.

Why is this? Do I need to return something from the checkValidatoinName function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is asynchronous, which means that it won't wait for the result to get back before proceeding. You're probably initializing `name` to `true` somewhere, and it's getting `true` the first time, but all the other times, it's `false`, because the AJAX from the first one finished and set it to `false`.

Try using [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of `$.post`, and set `async` to `false` in the options. The [`$.post` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) shows the options that `$.post` would give to `$.ajax`.

Comment: So how would i fix this? Can I make it so my .click function will run and then immediately after that another function will run?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how you'd make the AJAX request synchronous instead of asynchronous.

Comment: Tried using $.ajax with async: false. still doesn't do the trick.

Comment: I ended up just having to do the logic in the callback.